# Enumeration and two "Sub-Enumerations"

Tags: c#, architecture, enums

That's an architect question!

There are two conditionally independent enumerations

```
enum OpenID
{
  Google,
  Aol
}

enum OAuth
{
  Facebook,
  Twitter
}

class Provider 
{ 
  public OpenID openid;
  public OAuth oauth;
}
```

It is very logical to me to separate all members of the Providers set into OpenID and OAuth.

If (openid==null) // one behavior, If (oauth==null) // another behavior.

There will be an array of Provider instances which need to be sorted.

Is there any way

- to support this division (openid vs oauth) and
- add functionality to ARRANGE all X members arbitrary, e.g. { Facebook, Google, Aol, Twitter}
  WITHOUT IMPLEMENTING 3D ENUMERATION?

Meaning, if a value has been added to any of enums, say OAuth:
    enum OAuth
    {
      Facebook,
      Twitter,
      Instagram
    }

there will be no need to explicitly write this value (Instagram) somewhere else in the code to actually add support for sorting.

Ideas I bear in mind:

- Has a single enum anyway, but add prefix, 
  i.e. enum X { OpenID_Google, OpenID_Aol, OAuth_Facebook, OAuth_Twitter }.

downsize - no way to operate with enum A (or B) specific actions. 
Now I have a bool variable to indicate type: bool IsOpenId; bool IsOAuth;

- XML list
  { Facebook }, meaning first include/process Facebook, then members of OpenID, then rest of OAuth.

Have you any thunderstriking ideas? Maybe even with code examples!

Comment: Please provide a real sample of what you are trying to do, x, a and b don't convey any meaning. I did not understand what you are asking or trying to achieve.

Comment: Haven't got the foggiest idea what question you are asking!

Comment: Instead of trying to compare with null, consider adding an enumeration value 'None' into both enums with integer value 0.

Comment: @ColinE good to know that you have not, maybe someone does!

Comment: @gr9zev: Thanks, that cleared a lot of questions. One remains: How/where are you doing the sorting? Please show a sample of what you want to do, in Pseudocode is ok.

Comment: That's kind of open as well. providers.OrderBy(provider => providers.OpenID).ToList();

Comment: @gr9zev: So the following would be ok? `providers.OrderBy(x => x.OpenID).ThenBy(x => x.OAuth)` - isn't this already the solution?

Comment: see #2 in "Is there any way" part of the question. How I arrange them ARBITRARY? Want to have { Facebook (unusual position), Google (from enum), Aol (from enum), Twitter (from enum)}. HOW THIS ARRANGEMENT can be defined/implemented... something like that

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I omitted that for clarity. Have already the Undefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following, I suppose:

```
enum Provider
{
    None = 0,
    OpenID = 0x1,
    OAuth =  0x2,
    Google =   0x10 | OpenID,
    Aol =      0x20 | OpenID,
    Facebook = 0x30 | OAuth,
    Twitter =  0x40 | OAuth | OpenID // can set both flags!
}

static bool IsOpenID(Provider p)
{
    return (p & Provider.OpenID) == Provider.OpenID;
}
static bool IsOAuth(Provider p)
{
    return (p & Provider.OAuth) == Provider.OAuth;
}
```

This way you can define a sort order for the providers independent of if they're `OpenID` or `OAuth`.

This means that the last 8 bits of your enum give 8 potential "flags" for each auth type, of which `IsOpenID` takes the last bit and `OAuth` takes the next-to-last; there is space for 2 more flags for future expansion, given by `0x4` and `0x8`. Further expansion would require an extra trailing `0` on the non-flag values.

`IsOpenID` checks if the `OpenID flag` is `1` or `0`; similarly `IsOAuth` checks the `OAuth` flag.

Because the flags use the *low* bits of the enumeration, any sort on these values will reflect the "provider ID" part rather than the flags.

Comment: Good thinking, thanks for input. I'm saving text values, in this case should be reasonable instead of number values.

Comment: If you save the values as text, that's good - it means you can change the numbers underlying the values in the code without messing up all your stored data.

Comment: I heard of enums, starting with 0, would it be applicable here to specify explicitly only OAuth type "2 | OAuth" and have OpenID = 0 as default?

Comment: No, it's important that they have the values 1 and 2 (and that further ones will be 4, 8, 16 etc.) You could use a 0 value as "None".

Comment: Some providers support both modes, how can that be defined?

Comment: @gr9zev: I think you are taking a wrong road here. You should create two interfaces IOpenId and IOAuth and classes that implement these interfaces. Because as I see it, somewhere in your code with the enums you would have a huge switch statement...

Comment: @gr9zev You can set _both_ flags: `StackOverflow = 5 << 2 | OpenID | OAuth` will result in both `IsOpenID` and `IsOAuth` returning `true`.

Comment: `[Flags]` doesn't work here, because this isn't a true flags enumeration - it's part flags and part non-flags. It doesn't really matter though; `[Flags]` just tells the debugger to display something different.

Comment: In your previous to last paragraph you mean Future Provider TYPES? '<< 3' - means 3 bits to shift. Please change values to hex. Can the notation be reduced to Google = 0x10 | OpenID, so we reserve last hex-digit for TYPES to eliminate '<< X'? Append it as a new block if possible, thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer to give one hex digit to the "type", which gives you room for two more types.